# What does "Giving an overall running time" mean in this context?

Tags: algorithms

In the following image
[image: click me for an image because I need 10 rep first]

The author refers to an overall running time linear to |E|. But the author then says this is at most O(n^2). This seems contradictory because O(n^2) is quadratic time. Did the author mean to write something else? Or am I misunderstanding something?

**EDIT!: My question is: What does the author mean when writing "overall running time linear to |E|"?**

EDIT: More context, define E, which is all the edges and is stored as variable j: [image]

Comment: Let me know if y'all need more context and I'll post everything from the beginning of the chapter up to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, a simpler English version is this:

> The computation of $L(j)$ then takes time proportional to the indegree
>   of $j$, *as a result*, it takes time linear in $E$ *in total*.

Answer (score -1):

$n$ is the number of vertices and there are $O(n^2)$ edges in the graph.

Comment: What does the author mean when writing "overall running time linear to |E|"?

Comment: $|E|$ is the number of edges in the graph. Linear in the number of edges is quadratic in the number of vertices.